# ionic 5 (capacitor) gives NullInjectorError empty object Magnetometer can not access ionic-native functionality,

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5, capacitor-plugin

NullInjectorError: No provider for Magnetometer
My goal is to read sensordata, like magnetometer. Using Ionic 5, Angular, capacitor android.

You can find my project at https://github.com/kpproce/ionicMagnoMeter

I can't get access to the magnetometer, because the object is empty. I did manage to access the camera, but this is standard available in the web version also...

I understand that the magnetometer probably doesn't exist in the web app version.
There are many instructions about plugins, but could not get them working

followed instructions: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/magnetometer

To prepare: In the terminal VScode: 
--- npm install --save @ionic-native/core 
--- npm install cordova-plugin-magnetometer 
--- npm install @ionic-native/magnetometer 
--- npx cap add android

Code used: 
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Plugins } from  '@capacitor/core';
import { Magnetometer, MagnetometerReading } from '@ionic-native/Magnetometer/ngx';

...

export class HomePage {
constructor(private magnetometer: Magnetometer) {} // this seems to be the problem, empty object

[see error NullInjectorError: No provider for Magnetometer!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XH3fH.png)

Comment: Allready found a problem (thanx to Flavio): iimport { Magnetometer, MagnetometerReading } from '@ionic-native/magnetometer/ngx'; last m should not be capetilized. documentation is not clear: https://github.com/kpproce/ionicMagnoMeter

Comment: Solved problem (thx to..) in app.module.ts: at Magnetometer to providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }, Magnetometer],

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Answer (score -1):

See: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/getting-error-no-provider-for-mediaplugin/53570/5

Usually you add ionic native plugins like that:
add the plugin to your app with cli command

```
ionic plugin add --save PLUGINNAME
```

install the ionic native plugin from npm

```
npm install --save @ionic-native/PLUGINNAME
```

import it in your page/provider and in your app.module.ts

```
import {​​​​​​​​ PLUGINNAME }​​​​​​​​ from '@ionic-native/PLUGINNAME';
```

add it to your app.module.ts

```
providers: [ PLUGINNAME ]
```

use DI in your constructor in your page/provider

```
constructor(private pluginName: PLUGINNAME) {​​​​​​​​ }​​​​​​​​
```

then you can use it in your code